# Optimal transport between two distributions in a Markov chain

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains, calculus-of-variations, optimal-transportation

In a [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/278845/78539), given an ergodic Markov chain, I'm interesting in sampling as short a path as possible with prescribed distributions for its endpoints. In a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/a/278953/78539), I propose that the solution to this problem would be optimal transport with cost-function given by the *commute time distance* of the chain. I'm opening this new question to try and explore the OT connection better.

## Precise statement of the problem

Consider an ergodic Markov chain with state space $S$. Let $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$ be two distributions on $S$. Let $\Gamma(\pi_0,\pi_1)$ be the coupling polytope of joint distributions on $S \times S$ with marginals $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$ respectively. For example, if the state space $S$ is finite, then this is just the set of all nonnegative matrices with row sum $\pi_0$ and column sum $\pi_1$. Since the *commute time distance* (i.e the average time it takes to move from one state to another and back) defines a distance on $S$, it follows that the mapping

$$\Delta(\pi_0, \pi_1) := \operatorname{minimize}_{\gamma \in \Gamma(\pi_0,\pi_1)}\mathbb E_{(x,y) \sim \gamma}[\operatorname{CommuteTimeDistance}(x,y)],$$
defines a distance between distributions on $S$.

## Question

Is there an efficient way to compute such a distance ?

## Poorman's solution

In finite dimensions, it should be possible to use Sinkhorn iterations to solve an entropy regularized version of the above problem (this appears to be the SOTA method for solving large scale OT problems). I was wondering whether we can do better. That is, maybe a more "analytic" way to go about the problem.

---

## Euclidean embedding

[This paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2b92/f22a28db679a4c4e177a2a8bd956c48191ca.pdf?_ga=2.45889380.1951152750.1503360839-1593558864.1502823150) shows that if the state space $S$ is finite, say has $n$ elements, then it can be embedded into a euclidean space of dimension $\le n - 1$ via the mean commute time as follows. Let $L = U\Lambda U^T$ be the eigen-decomposition of Laplacian of the chain (note that $L$ is positive semi-definite). Finally, for $i \in S= \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, let $e_i$ be the $i$th unit vector in $\mathbb R^n$ and set $\psi_i := U{\Lambda^\dagger}^{1/2}e_i$. Then

$$\operatorname{CommuteTimeDistance}(i,j) = \|\psi_i - \psi_j\|_2^2.
$$

Comment: An even less "analytic" solution: The OT problem is a linear program and there are a several methods that are tuned OT problems. Hence you may try any LP solver or look for special solver for transport problems. (Of course, all in finite dimensions, but my bet is that there is no analytical way.)

Comment: @Dirk please see the last part of the question (naive solution). As I already mentioned there, there are indeed "fast" numerical methods to solve (approximations to ) this problem (e.g Sinkhorn iterations, etc.) with which I'm familiar.  I should mention that solving OT exactly (the linear programming problem) is out of hand when the dimensions is above a few hundreds.

Comment: The following work discusses the continuous-analog (Benamou-Brenier style) optimal transport on graphs/markov chains  :Maas, Jan. "Gradient flows of the entropy for finite Markov chains." Journal of Functional Analysis 261.8 (2011): 2250-2292.

Comment: Also see: Solomon, Justin, et al. "Continuous-flow graph transportation distances." arXiv preprint arXiv:1603.06927 (2016).

Comment: Well, you asked for efficiency, and tailored LP solvers for OT problems should be the fastest methods around for S up to a few thousand. Besides that, there is fast growing body of literature on analysis and numerics of OT problems.

Comment: In view of that, there is no answer to your question but a big list of pointers. If you could narrow down what you have in mind (more details of your problem and your aims) it may be easier to answer.